# Error message when installing ubuntu as dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, nouveau

It's my first time trying to install any OS as dualboot, and I'm having some problems doing so.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 off my USB. Before i install i run the check. It doesnt come up with any problems, and lets me reboot. Now here comes the problem. When rebooting this error message appears

```
[   272095]nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 3c3500 [ IBUS ]
[   5.272157]nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUBO: 10ecc0 ffffffff (1b40822c)
```

I have searched for some time now, and can't seem to figure out what can be done about this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It should be added, that when I try to install right away, it freezes few seconds after I initialize the installation

Comment: Taking a shot in the dark, but maybe try setting `nomodeset` in the GRUB:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu